# Environment variable for personal OneDrive account

Tags: environment-variables, onedrive

I have been using the `%OneDrive%` environment variable with my personal OneDrive account, however I connected my work OneDrive account and `%OneDrive%` now points to it instead.

Is there a OneDrive environment variable specifically for personal OneDrive accounts?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the environment variable for personal accounts is `%OneDriveConsumer%`